# Dropping UIView In ScrollView At A Specific Position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've figured out how to drag a view from one scrollView to another. What I'm trying to figure out now is how to position the view at the specific drop point when I stop dragging the view.

Currently when I drop the view it is slightly up and to the left than where I intended to drop it.

This is how I'm adding it into my new view once I've detected that dragging has stopped:

```
    CGPoint point = draggableView.center;
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.myView.frame, point)) {

            NSLog(@"Welp! My view is still inside side bar.");

            //Do Something Eventually

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Nice my view is within the bounds of the new scrollView.");

            //Troop is inside editing view, so add it
            [self.editingView addSubview:self.myView];
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the frame again of self.myview ?

Comment: Thanks for replying Pulkit. Just tried it by doing the following after my last line `self.myView.frame = self.myView.frame`. But it didn't change anything.

Comment: You're welcome. You set the same frame that myView already had. Debug and check the frame, you might have to position it again explicitly, not just assign it again to itself.